# Why would electrode reaction in galvanic cell stop when there's no neutrality in each cell?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

I know that the salt bridge produces ions to balance out the positive and negative ions in each solution, but why won't it work without a salt bride? Would it even work at the start since there's few electrons gained and lost and few ions produced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would work vanishingly briefly. The separation of charge that occurs when you connect two separated half cells without a salt bridge produces an electrostatic potential difference that opposes the electrochemical potential difference. The cell reaction would proceed until the two voltages balance, and it doesn't take much charge separation to hit the 1–2 volt electrochemical potential of typical cells, so this process is very fast.

Comment: Would it be correct to say this is like shorting a battery

Comment: @Buraian The effect is actually the complete opposite; more like sawing a battery in half and trying to connect a circuit to the two halves. When you short a battery, both half cells will proceed to react as fast as they can until they are limited by something else, e.g., mass transport.

Comment: @MichaelDMDryden It wouldn't occur "vanishingly briefly" -- after all, [these things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_anode) can last a while!

Comment: @ManRow If you look at the last paragraph in Theory: "For this protection to work there must be an electron pathway between the anode and the metal to be protected (e.g., a wire or direct contact) and an **ion pathway** between both the oxidizing agent (e.g., oxygen and water or moist soil) and the anode, and the oxidizing agent and the metal to be protected, thus forming a closed circuit; therefore simply bolting a piece of active metal such as zinc to a less active metal, such as mild steel, in air (a poor ionic conductor) will not furnish any protection. "

Comment: @MichaelDMDryden and what does that have to do with my comment?? Did you see me use the word "air" anywhere at all? I was replying to your answer and refuting your claim that a "no-salt-bridge" aka single cell galvanic current would last only "vanishingly briefly". I even gave you an example too -- the sacrificial anodes, like the kinds used on ship hulls, clearly do not function merely only "vanishingly briefly"! (nor do ships often complete their trips "vanishingly briefly" for that matter either)

Comment: @MichaelDMDryden you're assuming that "no salt bridge" means two separate / electrically disconnected solutions.. This is often not the case -- "no salt bridge" can also mean a single-cell electrochemical setup with two electrodes simply sharing one and the same solution without any special/extra "membranes" or added "salt-bridges" in between. In fact, [this entire industry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathodic_protection) pretty much relies on that single-cell operation principle as well...

Comment: In my answer, I am referring specifically to "separated half cells", as was implied by the mention of a condition of non-neutrality in the title. It is of course possible to create a galvanic cell without a salt bridge or membrane in a single solution (though it generally isn't a good idea if making a battery or performing an analytical experiment).

Comment: @MichaelDMDryden Ahh I see -- questions like "What if we remove component X" without also explicitly clarifying "And replace it with X", or Y, or simply "nothing at all", often seem vague to me. It's like in an electronic circuit if someone asks, "What if we remove this resistor?" -- it's not clear if they mean also "disconnect the terminals completely too" or "just short them with a plain wire instead without using any components at all"